# Filter only one value/line on line chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a line chart with two lines that show attendance scores for each gender (male and female). I would like to only apply/filter one of the lines while the other is disabled from filtering.

This will allow viewers to compare the overall numbers (both genders) with the filtered numbers (each seperate gender). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a slicer to select between different measures.

You would have to create two new measures (One filtered for male data and other filtered for female data). Using the slicer you can switch between the two measures and achieve what you are looking for.

The following link details the steps:

https://www.burningsuit.co.uk/blog/2018/03/dax-how-to-use-a-slicer-to-select-different-measures/

Comment: Thanks, I know how to filter the attendance by female and male on a line graph, but how do I add the total attendance for both on the same graph, so it would end up having 3 lines instead of just two?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i am wrong but why are you not summing the both attendance in other column and then use it as you want (else might be i dint got your question correctly)

Comment: I have the overall attendance in a column, this is what I'm using. However when I apply the gender to the legend, it gets rid of the line and creates two filtered lines for each gender. I want those two filtered lines as-well as the original overall line

Comment: calculate (sum(genders), all(tablename) )

use this type of measures it will work